# React js image is blank in safari

Tags: css, ios, reactjs, image, safari

I'm developing a page in React js and I need to display a logo of the the company. I get the image url from the API response and if there is no image url returned I need to display a default logo (stored locally). I import the default logo the following way:

```
import defaultLogo from "../images/logo.png";
```

and set the logo from API response like this:

```
const [logo, setLogo] = useState();

// then I set the image url inside the API call function
setLogo(result.data.logo);
```

and display the logo in the component like this:

```
<img
alt="logo"
src={logo ? logo : defaultLogo}>
</img>
```

Everything is working in the webview and android (I can see API logo and default logo), but in safari `defaultLogo` is displayed as a blank image (only alt is visible). I can't seem to figire out what is the issue, any advise is greatly appericated.

Comment: The image from a API is a .svg image?

Comment: no, also png (as url)s saved in file storage) and API images are displayed in safari, only defaultLogo is blank.

Comment: An `img` should be a single tag like `<img alt="logo" src={logo ? logo : defaultLogo}/>`.

Comment: @yousoumar, the issue is that this works on the chrome, android webview etc, only safari doesn't display the image. So if the img tag was a problem, safari wouldn't display logo either, safari just doesn't display defaultLogo.